# How to use regex in graphql query with gatsby

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, e-commerce, gatsby

I have created page query for my individual product page.

It does goes to an individual product and I want to add a filter like if multiple product has similar SKU I need to show them. Query works fine in Grphiql interface but in code it only show one node.

Grahiql Query

```
query ($id: String, $sku: String) {
  productsCsv(id: {eq: $id}) {
    id
    name
    productCategory
    sizes
    sku
    stock
    instock
    description
    colors
    templateKey
    price
    discount
    fields {
      slug
    }
  }
  allProductsCsv(filter: {sku: {regex: $sku}, instock: {eq: "TRUE"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        instock
        stock
        sku
        colors
        sizes
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In query Variables section, I am passing variable like this

```
{
 "sku": "/DW20DK18/"
}
```

allProductCsv only resulted in one node in gatsby though it returns multiple nodes in graphiql

Gatsby-node.js

```
const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem")
const path = require(`path`)


const onCreateNode = ({node,actions,getNode}) => {
    const {createNodeField} = actions
    if(node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
        const value = createFilePath({node, getNode})
        createNodeField({
            name:`slug`,
            node,
            value
        })
    }
    if(node.internal.type === `ProductsCsv`) {
        const value = node.name
        const processedSlug = value.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        createNodeField({
            name:`slug`,
            node,
            value: processedSlug
        })
    }
}

const createPages = async ({actions,graphql}) => {
    const {createPage} = actions
    const result = await graphql(`
    {
        allMarkdownRemark {
            edges {
                node {
                    frontmatter {
                    productColors
                    age
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        allProductsCsv {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    sku
                    fields{
                        slug
                    }
                    templateKey
                    productCategory
                }
            }
        }
    }
    `)
    if(result.errors){
        console.error(result.errors)
    }
    result.data.allProductsCsv.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
        console.log(node.productCategory)
        createPage({
            path: `${String(node.productCategory)}/${node.fields.slug}`,
            component: path.resolve(
                `src/templates/${String(node.templateKey)}.js`
            ),
            context: {
                id: node.id,
                sku: `/${node.sku}/`.toString(). //Passing SKU from Here
            }
        })
    })
}

module.exports = {
    /*
    1. function for how to create page
    2. On create node
    */

    onCreateNode,
    createPages
};
```

I am passing SKU along side of ID in Context in gatsby-node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your workaround should work except for the fact that you are using a template literal to hold a dynamic regular expression. For this approach I would try to do something like:

```
        context: {
            id: node.id,
            sku: new RegExp(String.raw `${node.sku}`, 'i'), //add other flags if needed 
        }
```

Alternatively try:

```
new RegExp(node.sku, 'i').toString()
```

The `RegExp` constructor should do the trick for this use-case with a little trick to force a raw string (since the comparison within GraphQL needs to be represented by a string value).

Comment: Thanks Ferran for taking to helping me out.
After updating, it started giving me error like
GraphQLError: Variable "$sku" got invalid value {}; String cannot represent a non string value: {}

Comment: I've added two more trials. I believe this should do the trick for your `new RegExp(node.sku, 'i').toString()`